# Update managed bean with ajax ignoring the required

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to update `idOutput` everytime that I change the value of `selectOneMenu`, but when it changes once a time to a value different of `null` I can't asign `null` another time, I think that is due to the `required="true"`, but I don't know how to avoid the validation only in the ajax request.

Here is the code:

Bean:

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class ProbeNull implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1628174277372407129L;
    private Boolean probe;
    public ProbeNull()
    {
        super();
    }
    public void show()
    {
        System.err.println("Value : " + probe);
    }
    public void save()
    {
        System.err.println("Save : " + probe);
    }
    public Boolean getProbe()
    {
        return probe;
    }
    public void setProbe(Boolean probe)
    {
        System.err.println("Setter: " + probe);
        this.probe = probe;
    }
}
```

xhtml:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
        <h:head />
        <h:body>
            <h:outputText id="idOutput" value="#{probeNull.probe}" />
            <h:form id="form">
                <p:selectOneMenu id="select" required="true" value="#{probeNull.probe}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select one" itemValue="#{null}" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="true" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="false" />
                    <p:ajax update=":idOutput" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:commandButton value="Save" ajax="false" action="#{probeNull.save()}" />
            </h:form>
            <h:form>
                <p:commandButton value="Show value" ajax="false" action="#{probeNull.show()}" />
            </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </html>
```

How can avoid it?

Comment: Why would you want to assign `null`?

Comment: This is a simplified version of my code, I want to get the `Boolean` value to add a different value node on a tree depending on the value, or not add anything if it's null.

Comment: The option would be `null` if nothing was selected. Once something has been selected, why would you want to set it back to null and destroy the selection made by the user? If you want the user to be able to make "no selection", then you shouldn't make the field required.

Comment: No, I don't want that the user have selected the `Select one` option when he submits the form but I want to update the `idOutput` always with the managed bean value (modified by ajax on each change in the `selectOneMenu`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want by using two remoteCommand tags and JavaScript.

```
<p:remoteCommand name="makeSelection" process="select" update=":idOutput" />
<p:remoteCommand name="clearSelection" process="@this" update="select,:idOutput" >
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{null}" target="#{probeNull.probe}" />  
</p:remoteCommand>
```

Now you can decide which one to call using a javascript funcion

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="select" required="true" value="#{probeNull.probe}" onchange="selectFunction(this)">
...

function selectFunction(el){
    //if el.value is empty you call clearSelection();
    //else you call makeSelection();
}
```

Don't forget to delete the `<p:ajax update=":idOutput" />`